# Need to defrost my Fisher Paykel refrigerator

Tags: refrigerator

A repair person came and is unable to thaw the water line for ice. It is connected through the cabinets and then inside the refrigerator it is too high to use a air dryer.

He suggested I defrost the refrigerator.
I am not exactly sure how to do that.

I turned the heat all the way up on the controls. The icemaker is not working and have had two different things replaced and he is still unable to thaw the water line so I can have ice.

Help!

Comment: If the water line is frozen before it reaches the fridge then defrosting the fridge will **not** thaw the line. "*Frozen*" implies that the temperature behind your cabinet is **below 32 degrees F.**   ??  To defrost your fridge unplug it for 24 hours and open the doors. Store your food in coolers.  **There is more to this story, we need more info**.

Answer (score 1):

Unplug the fridge and open the doors.

Of course, you'll probably want to do something with all the food so it doesn't spoil...

Comment: And you'll want to be ready for a lot of water dripping down towards the floor.